# What is the Facebook App Event name for "subscribe" in the API?

Tags: facebook-analytics

Looking at the [Event API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/), I can't find the name for the "subscribe" event (it does, however, have a constant in the SDK docs). Any idea what is the correct name I should use for this event?

Answer (score 0):

"Subscribe"
Found the answer here, in case anyone is wondering:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.m